# How to write following Select in sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I wanted get id of something whose barcode is either empty or barcode state is active. Barcode state is stored in another table. Here is what I tried

```
SELECT a.id from a 
       where a.bar='' 
          OR a.bar=(SELECT b.barcode from b where b.barcode=active)
```

But it gives me nothing when there are some results should come. Where did I make mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: and also check datatypes of every column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id FROM a 
       WHERE a.bar=''  
          OR a.bar IN (SELECT b.barcode FROM b WHERE b.barcode='active')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use raw query:

here is the code for it

```
Cursor getData(String a){

     return db.rawQuery(SELECT a.id from a where a.bar='' OR a.bar=(SELECT b.barcode from b where b.barcode=active));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your subquery returns more than one record so in this case you have to use `IN` instead of `=`. Also I guess `b.barcode` is a varchar field so you should use a varchar constant `'active'`

```
SELECT a.id from a 
       where a.bar='' 
          OR a.bar IN (SELECT b.barcode from b where b.barcode='active')
```